# how do I add fields to a namedtuple?

Tags: python, namedtuple

I am working with a list of namedtuples. I would like to add a field to each named tuple after it has already been created. It seems I can do that by just referencing it as an attribute (as in `namedtuple.attribute = 'foo'`), but then it isn't added to the list of fields. Is there any reason why I shouldn't do it this way if I don't do anything with the fields list? Is there a better way to add a field?

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> result = namedtuple('Result',['x','y'])
>>> result.x = 5
>>> result.y = 6
>>> (result.x, result.y)
(5, 6)
>>> result.description = 'point'
>>> (result.x, result.y, result.description)
(5, 6, 'point')
>>> result._fields
('x', 'y')
```

Comment: And why don't you just use dict? dict.keys for sure will have added 'fields'.

Comment: they are immutable, just like tuples, so they are not a fit for such a scenario and way of building them up in multiple statements like that. you should use other python language constructs if you really want to mutate a record type in python. regular classes, dicts, or dataclasses come to mind, offering different features of economy and syntax each.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you do works because [`namedtuple(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) returns a **new class**. To actually get a Result object, you instantiate that class. So the correct way is:

```
Result = namedtuple('Result', ['x', 'y'])
result = Result(5, 6)
```

And you'll find that adding attributes to these objects does *not* work. So the reason you shouldn't do it is because it doesn't work. Only abusing the class objects works, and I hope I don't need to go into detail why this is a horrible, horrible idea.

Note that regardless of whether you can add attributes to namedtuples or not (and even if you list all attributes you need beforehand), you cannot change a namedtuple object after it's created. Tuples are immutable. So if you need to change objects after creation for any reason, in any way or shape, you can't use `namedtuple`. You're better off defining a custom class (some of the stuff `namedtuple` adds for you doesn't even make sense for mutable objects).

Answer (score 13):

Notice that here you're modifying the `type` of the named tuples, not instances of that type.  In this case, you'd probably want to create a new type with an additional field from the old one:

```
result = namedtuple('Result',result._fields+('point',))
```

e.g.:

```
>>> result = namedtuple('Result',['x','y'])
>>> result = namedtuple('Result',result._fields+('point',))
>>> result._fields
('x', 'y', 'point')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily concatenate namedtuples, keeping in mind that they are immutable

```
from collections import namedtuple

T1 = namedtuple('T1', 'a,b')
T2 = namedtuple('T2', 'c,d')

t1 = T1(1,2)
t2 = T2(3,4)

def sum_nt_classes(*args):
    return namedtuple('_', ' '.join(sum(map(lambda t:t._fields, args), ())))

def sum_nt_instances(*args):
    return sum_nt_classes(*args)(*sum(args,()))

print sum_nt_classes(T1,T2)(5,6,7,8)
print sum_nt_instances(t1,t2)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the meaning of these functions, could you please expand that? Why do you sum fields of named tuples?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add a new field to a `namedtuple` after defining it. Only way is to create a new template and creating new `namedtuple` instances.

**Analysis**

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> result = namedtuple('Result',['x','y'])
>>> result
<class '__main__.Result'>
```

`result` is not a tuple, but the class which creates tuples.

```
>>> result.x
<property object at 0x02B942A0>
```

You create a new tuple like this:

```
>>> p = result(1, 2)
>>> p
Result(x=1, y=2)

>>> p.x
1
```

Prints the value `x` in `p`.

```
>>> p.x = 5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    p.x = 5
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

This throws error because tuple is immutable.

```
>>> result.x = 5
>>> result
<class '__main__.Result'>
>>> result._fields
('x', 'y')
>>> p = result(1, 2)
>>> p
Result(x=1, y=2)
```

This doesn't change anything.

```
>>> result.description = 'point'
>>> result
<class '__main__.Result'>
>>> result._fields
('x', 'y')
```

This doesn't change anything either.

**Solution**

```
>>> result = namedtuple('Result', ['x','y'])
>>> p = result(1, 2)
>>> p
Result(x=1, y=2)
>>> # I need one more field
>>> result = namedtuple('Result',['x','y','z'])
>>> p1 = result(1, 2, 3)
>>> p1
Result(x=1, y=2, z=3)
>>> p
Result(x=1, y=2)
```