# Adding a new property to namedTuple instance in python and convert to dict

Tags: python, casting, namedtuple

I am trying to add a new property to a named tuple in which I want to store some values. Post that I want to convert it back to JSON to pass it as a parameter in api. I found an answer to add a property to a namedTuple however it creates a type and doesn't modify the instance itself. What is the best way to achieve above functionality.

[how do I add fields to a namedtuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324644/how-do-i-add-fields-to-a-namedtuple)

```
def _json_object_hook(d): 
    return namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
def json2obj(data):
    return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    registrationResponse = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=registrationkey)
    registrationResponse = registrationResponse['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    registration = json2obj(registrationResponse)   
    abc = namedtuple('registration',registration._fields+('point',))
    y = abc._asdict()  # TypeError: _asdict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

On debugger

```
type(abc) #<class 'type'>
type(registration) #<class '__main__.X'>    
registration #<X, len() = 7>    
abc #<class '__main__.registration'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`namedtuple` does not create a namedtuple. It creates a class you should then instantiate:

```
Record = namedtuple('Record', "a b")
```

If you have data in a dict like,

```
d1 = dict(a=1, b=2)
```

You can instantiate a similar record from it with:

```
r1 = Record(**d1)
```

Do not change namedtuple fields because, like tuples, they are supposed to be immutable.

In alternative add/change dict keys, build a new `Record` class based in its keys and instantiate the namedtuple from the dict, to access through field names.